# How to remap "dead_hook" in Emacs and Vim?

Tags: x11, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I would like to remap some common symbols like `(` and `)` to the base line of my keyboard combining <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> with other keys like <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd>.

I can remap <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to `)` because that combination prints [`ĸ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kra_%28letter%29). The problem with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> is that combination is the dead key ["hook above"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_above), so I can't remap the symbol.

I don't want to modify the Xorg config/files because I want a portable config between different computers. I'm only interested in the config for the text editors.

The output of `xev` for the keys combination is:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x39a, subw 0x0, time 15760149, (170,-16), root:(170,36),
    state 0x10, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x39a, subw 0x0, time 15760673, (170,-16), root:(170,36),
    state 0x90, keycode 44 (keysym 0xfe61, dead_hook), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x39a, subw 0x0, time 15760753, (170,-16), root:(170,36),
    state 0x90, keycode 44 (keysym 0xfe61, dead_hook), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x39a, subw 0x0, time 15761115, (170,-16), root:(170,36),
    state 0x90, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I'm using `setxkbmap -layout "es" -option "lv3:caps_switch"` to configure the keyboard.

For Emacs:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "ĸ") (kbd ")"))
```

For Vim:

```
imap ĸ )
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you running GVim or Vim in a terminal? If a terminal, which terminal emulator? What graphical toolkit is the Emacs binary built against (if you don't know: which package of what distribution are you using)?

Comment: Emacs built against GTK3 and GVim. The distro is Arch Linux.